# Explanation results of RC simulation wih LTspice/Micro-cap

Tags: simulation, ltspice, basic

I built a basic schema with resistor, capacitor, ground and a battery in LTspice and MicroCap.
I used transient analysis mode.

I expected to see on a plot showing decreasing current and increasing voltage during launch eventually stabilising at 0A. For the voltage I was expecting the opposite (starting out at 0V and stabilising at `Vbat`), but I only get flat lines where capacitor voltage is equal to battery voltage from `t = 0` and current 0A.

I wanted to prove time to charge rule for capacitor where `T = 5RC`.

I played with various time ranges and time steps but no luck.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For LTSpice, you'll want to add an initial condition for the cap.
There are multiple ways to do this, the simplest is to modify the part value like so:

[image]

On a cap the ic set the initial voltage.  On an inductor is sets the initial current.  You can also specify node voltages etc.
[ltwiki](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/_IC_set_initial_conditions.htm) topic on initial conditions has more details.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Default behavior is not intuitive, because in reality nobody charges my capacitors if I would experiment with a real oscilloscope. I am curious why team made such decision cause it makes entry level higher. Lot's of beginners probably resigned from the app because of this feature.

Answer (score 2):

By default LTspice starts the simulation with capacitors charged to the steady state voltage. Here are some ways to make it start discharged.

1. In *'Edit Simulation Command'* select the option *'start external DC supply voltages at 0V'*, or add *'startup'* to the `.tran` directive.
2. Make the battery into a 'pulse' voltage starting at 0V and going to its normal voltage after a short time delay.
3. Wire a switch or transistor across the capacitor and momentarily turn it on with a voltage pulse.